# How to read Session timeout value from web.config using javascript in JS file

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Can anyone please guide me to read the value of Session timeout value using javascript contained in a .js file.

I need to access the value in a javascript file and process the value.

I tried to follow the below approach in a test.js file but it is not working:

```
var sessionTimeout = <%= Session.Timeout %>;
alert(sessionTimeout);
```

Comment: You need to register your js file so that the .net code is evaluated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that .JS files are not executed so they do not contain the Session.Timeout variable.

You can do two things:

1. Include your javascript directly in your ASP/ASPX page that does have the code being executed.
2. Register your JS script in your code.

**Registering your JS**

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479011.aspx#aspnet-usingjavascript_topic07

```
Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("MyScript", _
   "<script language=javascript src='MyJavaScriptFile.js'>")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to all for giving the reply. I am currently working in an asp.net mvc2 project and the following code helped me to resolve the issue of getting session timeout in javascript file.  malcolms reply helped me a lot. http://forums.asp.net/t/1520041.aspx/1

Comment: All working ok? If it worked could you accept the answer thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I have share m code which I use for connection string from this code you can replace logic for session.

```
<script language="javascript" type ="text/javascript"> 
function ReadWebConfig()
{
    var strCon = '<%=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MysqlCon"].ConnectionString %>'
    alert(strCon);
    var strTemp = '<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WordTemplate"].ToString() %>'
    alert(strTemp);
}
</script>
```